# JAVA: AbstractMethodError while deploying application in Tomcat

Tags: java, jar, comparator

I am getting following Error while deploying my web application and when i have debugged i have found there is problem with my .jar file
I am sure that my deployment procedure is correct
ERROR while deploying application is:

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method
>   I/Z.compare(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)I is abstract    at
>   I.Z.compare(Unknown Source)

This I.Z.Compare method looks like below if I decompile my .jar file
[image]

I also have correct .jar file but didnt have its source code. The I.Z.compare  looks like below:
[image]

For the former .jar file. The code which is responsible for the generation of this method looks like below:

```
static Comparator comparator()
    {
      return new Comparator()
        {
          public int compare(Object o1,Object o2)
          {
            return Range.compare((Range)o1,(Range)o2);
          }
        };
    }
```

Everything is present in compare function. Still it is not reflecting in .jar file
Below is my Build.xml:

```
<project name="SafePerimeter" default="pack_release" basedir=".">
    <description>
        SafePerimeter Build File
    </description>
    <!-- versions -->    
    <property name="versionNumber" value="3.1.7"/>   

    <!-- copyright year -->
    <property name="copyYear" value="2009"/>

    <!-- set global properties for this build -->
    <property name="source" location="source"/>
    <property name="lib" location="lib" />
    <property name="versionSource" location="work/vsource"/>
    <property name="build" location="work/build"/> 
    <property name="mapping" location="work/mapping"/>   
    <property name="targetlib"  location="work/lib"/>
    <property name="idgen"  location="tools/ant/idgen"/>  
    <property name="legal"  location="legal"/>
    <property name="version"  location="version"/>
    <property name="dist"  location="work/dist"/>
    <property name="work"  location="work"/>
    <property name="package"  location="work/package"/>  
    <property name="packageNamePrefix" value="cw-safeperimeter-"/>
    <property name="context"  location="context"/>      

    <target name="init">
      <!-- Create the time stamp -->
      <tstamp/>
      <buildnumber file="${idgen}/id.txt"/>
      <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
      <delete dir="${dist}"/>
      <delete dir="${package}"/>      
      <mkdir dir="${dist}"/>      
      <mkdir dir="${package}"/>      
      <mkdir dir="${build}"/>      
      <mkdir dir="${versionSource}"/>
      <mkdir dir="${idgen}"/>
      <mkdir dir="${targetlib}"/>
      <mkdir dir="${mapping}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="version" depends="init"> 
      <touch file="${source}/com/collabworx/redball/PerimeterEngine.java"/>
      <filter token="DATE" value="${DSTAMP}"/>
      <filter token="TIME" value="${TSTAMP}"/>          
      <filter token="BUILD" value="${build.number}"/>
      <filter token="VERSION" value="${versionNumber}"/>
      <filter token="COPYYEAR" value="${copyYear}"/> 
      <copy todir="${versionSource}" filtering="true">
        <fileset dir="${source}"/>
      </copy>
    </target>        

    <target name="compile" depends="version">    
    <javac srcdir="${versionSource}" destdir="${build}" debug="off" optimize="on">
      <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${lib}">
          <include name="**/*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
      </classpath>
    </javac>            
    </target>         

    <target name="make_library" depends="compile">   
         <java jar="tools/jshrink/jshrink.jar" fork="true" output="${mapping}/redball_lib_rename.log">                  
         <arg line=" ${build} -license '06/05/2003 CollabWorx, Inc. RWKWKQWMFOYQGUEC' -script tools/obfuscation/redball_lib_obf.txt -o ${targetlib}/sp.jar -classpath lib/servlet.jar;lib/activation.jar;lib/mail.jar"/>                                        
         <classpath>
           <pathelement location="/tools/jshrink/jshrink.jar"/>
           <fileset dir="${lib}">
             <include name="**/*.jar"/>
           </fileset>
         </classpath>
       </java>
    </target> 

    <target name="compile_debug" depends="version">    
    <javac srcdir="${versionSource}" destdir="${build}" debug="on">
      <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${lib}">
          <include name="**/*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
      </classpath>
    </javac>            
    </target>

    <target name="jar_debug" depends="compile_debug">    
        <jar destfile="${targetlib}/sp.jar" basedir="${build}"/>           
    </target> 

    <target name="prepare_package">
        <!-- re-declaring tokens to make sure they are applied when antcall is
        used -->
        <filter token="DATE" value="${DSTAMP}"/>
        <filter token="TIME" value="${TSTAMP}"/>          
        <filter token="BUILD" value="${build.number}"/>
        <filter token="VERSION" value="${versionNumber}"/>
        <filter token="COPYYEAR" value="${copyYear}"/> 
        <copy todir="${package}/${packageNamePrefix}${versionNumber}"> 
        <fileset dir="./" casesensitive="false">                                                        
          <include name="web-inf/**/*"/>                                               
        </fileset>                     
      </copy>
      <copy todir="${package}" filtering="true"> 
        <fileset dir="${context}" casesensitive="false">                                                        
          <include name="*.xml"/>
          <include name="*.properties"/>
        </fileset>                    
      </copy>
      <copy todir="${package}/${packageNamePrefix}${versionNumber}"> 
        <fileset dir="./" casesensitive="false">   
          <include name="docs/**/*"/>                                                                                              
        </fileset>      
        <fileset dir="jsp" casesensitive="false">                                       
          <include name="**/*"/>                                                                
        </fileset>        
      </copy>
      <copy todir="${package}/${packageNamePrefix}${versionNumber}" filtering="true" overwrite="true">        
        <fileset dir="jsp" casesensitive="false">                                       
          <include name="simjsp/footer.jsp"/>                                                                
        </fileset>        
      </copy>
      <copy todir="${package}/${packageNamePrefix}${versionNumber}/web-inf/lib">
        <fileset dir="${targetlib}" casesensitive="false">
          <include name="sp.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${lib}" >
          <exclude name="**/activation.jar"/>
          <exclude name="**/mail.jar"/>
          <exclude name="**/servlet.jar"/>
        </fileset>
      </copy>
      <copy todir="${package}/${packageNamePrefix}${versionNumber}" filtering="true">
            <fileset dir="${legal}"/>
      </copy>
      <copy todir="${package}/${packageNamePrefix}${versionNumber}" filtering="true">
            <fileset dir="${version}"/>
        </copy> 
    </target>

        <target name="prepare_package_debug" depends="jar_debug"> 
            <antcall target="prepare_package"/>
      </target>

        <target name="prepare_package_release" depends="make_library"> 
                <antcall target="prepare_package"/>
        </target>

        <target name="pack">          
          <zip destfile="${dist}/${packageNamePrefix}${versionNumber}.${build.number}.zip" basedir="${package}"/>            
      </target> 

    <target name="pack_release" depends="prepare_package_release" description="creates release package">          
        <antcall target="pack"/>            
    </target> 

        <target name="pack_debug" depends="prepare_package_debug" description="creates debug package">          
            <antcall target="pack"/>            
      </target>

    <target name="cleanup" description="deletes work directories">    
      <delete dir="${work}"/>            
    </target>

        <target name="cleanup_for_eclipse" description="deletes work directories except eclipse directory">    
            <delete includeemptydirs="true">
                <fileset dir="${work}">
                    <exclude name="bin/**/*"/>
                </fileset>      
            </delete>
        </target>

    <target name="deploy_jsp">
        <!-- re-declaring tokens to make sure they are applied when antcall is
            used -->
            <filter token="DATE" value="${DSTAMP}"/>
            <filter token="TIME" value="${TSTAMP}"/>          
            <filter token="BUILD" value="${build.number}"/>
            <filter token="VERSION" value="${versionNumber}"/>
            <filter token="COPYYEAR" value="${copyYear}"/> 

        <copy todir="${package}/${packageNamePrefix}${versionNumber}">          
            <fileset dir="jsp" casesensitive="false">                                       
              <include name="**/*"/>                                                                
            </fileset>        
          </copy>
          <copy todir="${package}/${packageNamePrefix}${versionNumber}" filtering="true" overwrite="true">        
            <fileset dir="jsp" casesensitive="false">                                       
              <include name="simjsp/footer.jsp"/>                                                                
            </fileset>        
          </copy>
    </target>
</project>
```

In the build.xml file. There is one obfuscator which is renaming the functions and on analyzing its log, I have found that my understanding of flow is correct but there is one error coming in that log file of obfuscator:

> Could not find java/util/Comparator.class on Classpath

If you need more info. I can provide that. I have spent a lot of time in figuring this out. Please help me!

Comment: Clearly, your obfuscator is not finding your Java SDK jars.   You'll need to review the use instructions for it and correct any classpath / $JAVA_HOME problems you are having.

Comment: agree with BadZen, not finding your dependencies jars

Comment: Have you figured this out? I've also run into a very similar problem, and my finding so far is that JShrink cannot decipher some class files that come with JDK8 (Most likely ones with "default interface methods", such as java/util/Comparator, and java/lang/CharSequence).
In my research, I've noticed some earlier versions of Scala also had problems with these interface class files.